# Anti-holomorphic involution of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I wonder if anti-holomorphic involution of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is, up to change of coordinate, given by either 
$$
z\mapsto \overline{z}, \ \ \,z\mapsto -\overline{z}, \ \ \ or  \ \ \ z\mapsto \frac{1}{\overline{z}}, 
$$
where $z$ is an inhomogeneous coordinate of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: in fact $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ becomes $z\mapsto -\overline{z}$ if you replace $z$ with $iz$. And yes, there are just two involutions, up to change of coordinate.