# Quotient of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by antiholomorphic involution

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

On $\mathbb{CP}^1\ni(X_1:X_2)$ let $z=X_1/X_2$ be one of the two charts,
and define an involution map $$I^-:z \mapsto -\frac{1}{\overline{z}}.$$

Question: how to prove that the quotient $\mathbb{CP}^1/I^- \cong \mathbb{RP}^2$ ?

---

Another related issue: is there a simple way to prove that, up to diffeomorphism, the only involutions of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are $z \mapsto \pm \frac{1}{\overline{z}}$ ?

Comment: Is considering how the identification works on the closed unit disk cheating?

Comment: well, suppose I don't give you the RHS of the thesis

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of using the map of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419088/finding-the-inverse-of-a-map-from-cp1-to-s2

Comment: Also, this can be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199015/anti-holomorphic-involution-of-mathbbp1?rq=1

Comment: If you use that map, all you need to do is write $z \mapsto -1/\overline{z}$ in homogeneous coordinates. A little algebraic manipulation will show that it becomes the antipodal map on $S^2$.

Comment: Indeed it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just answering your main question, from the perspective of projective geometry. The map $z\mapsto\frac1{\bar z}$ is the inversion in the unit circle. But you are not only inverting, but then also reflecting in the origin. So points on the unit circle will be paired with points on the unit circle in the opposite direction. Points inside the unit circle will be paired with points outside. The origin will be paired with the point at infinity.

Now you can perform a [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of the complex plane onto the [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). You will find that your paired points end up as [antipodal points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point) on the sphere. And the set of all points on the sphere, with antipodal points identified, is just the real projective plane. You can simply take the 3D coordinates of these points as homogenous coordinates, and the antipodal point will be the representant which has all coordinates negated and thus represents the same point, so the pairing fits in with homogenous coordinates there.